# How to VLOOKUP based on two column criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I'm not exactly sure if this calls for a vlookup, but it's the closest I could think of to solve the following scenario:

```
Animal|Color|Total
------------------
Cat   |Red  |150
Cat   |Blue |85
Cat   |Green|10
Dog   |Red  |120
Dog   |Blue |64
Dog   |Green|16
```

How would I write a formula for the above table to pull out the Total(85) for an Animal=Cat & Color=Blue?

Comment: Use SUMIFS(): `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Cat",B:B,"Blue")`

Comment: Wow, that's a short and amazing answer! Unfortunately, I should have provided an example with the last column being text instead of a number. Is there a way to get it to work with text as well?

Comment: Use FILTER: `FILTER(C:C,A:A="Cat",B:B="Blue")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's perfect!